# Inserting new record from AngularJS using Web API

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

Hi I'm a newbie in web development and I'm having some trouble in inserting new data in my database.

First, there's an error in dbcontext.Tbl_Articles.Add(adto);
It says, cannot convert WebAPI.Models.Articles to WebAPI.DataLayer.Tbl_Articles

Another thing is, whenever I run my Web API, it says something like this - {"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}
script file:

```
$scope.AddArticle = function ()
{
    var data =
        {
            Category: $scope.Category,
            IsCarousel: $scope.IsCarousel,
            IsImportant: $scope.IsImportant,
            HeaderImage: $scope.HeaderImage,
            Title: $scope.Title,
            ByLine: $scope.ByLine,
            Content: $scope.Content,
            Author: $scope.Author,
            PublishStartDate: $scope.PublishStartDate_date + " " + $scope.PublishStartDate_time + $scope.PublishStartDate_time_ext,
            PublishEndDate: $scope.PublishEndDate_date + " " + $scope.PublishEndDate_time + $scope.PublishEndDate_time_ext
        };

    $http(
        {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://project-aphrodite-uat-service.azurewebsites.net/api/articles/createarticle',
            data: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
        .then(function successCallback(response)
        {
            console.log(response);
        },
        function errorCallback(response)
        {
            console.log("error" + response);
        });

};
```

ArticlesController.cs:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/articles/createarticle")]
    public Articles CreateArticle(Articles obj)
    {
        DataLayer.DataLayer dl = new DataLayer.DataLayer();
        dl.CreateArticle(obj);
        return obj;
    }
```

DataLayer.cs:

```
    public string CreateArticle(Articles obj)
    {
        var adto = new Articles();
        adto.Category = obj.Category;
        adto.IsCarousel = obj.IsCarousel;
        adto.IsImportant = obj.IsImportant;
        adto.HeaderImage = obj.HeaderImage;
        adto.Title = obj.Title;
        adto.ByLine = obj.ByLine;
        adto.Content = obj.Content;
        adto.Author = obj.Author;
        adto.PublishStartDate = obj.PublishStartDate;
        adto.PublishEndDate = obj.PublishEndDate;

        using (ArticleEntities dbcontext = new ArticleEntities())
        {
            dbcontext.Tbl_Articles.Add(adto);
            dbcontext.SaveChanges();

            return "test";
        }
    }
```

I hope someone could help me fix these. Thankie so much!

Comment: why there are two CreateArticle?

Comment: The CreateArticle in the controller calls the method within my DataLayer to execute the inserting of records but unfortunately, my code doesn't work. Do you have idea on how to fix these?

Comment: @Sajeetharan i dont have team viewer